# Weakly$*$ convergent sequence of signed measures $\Rightarrow$ Sequence of total variation measures bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a second-countable locally compact Hausdorff space. Denote by $C_c$ the space of continuous functions $f : E \to \mathbb{R}$ with compact support and by $M$ the space of signed Borel measures on $E$. Write $\mu f := \int f \, d\mu$ for $f \in C_c$ and $\mu \in M$ and denote by $|\mu|$ the total variation measure of $\mu$.

Assume that $\mu_n f \to \mu f$ for all $f \in C_c$. Then $\sup_n |\mu_n f| < \infty$ for all $f \in C_c$. Does it even hold $\sup_n |\mu_n| f < \infty$ for all $f \in C_c$, $f \geq 0$ or that $\sup_n |\mu_n|(K) < \infty$ for all compact $K \subseteq E$?

Remark:

1. This is clearly true if $E = K$ is compact since then $C_c = C(K)$ is a Banach space and we can apply the uniform boundedness principle which yields $\sup_n\lVert \mu_n \rVert < \infty$, whence $\sup_n |\mu_n| f \leq \sup_n \lVert \, |\mu_n| \, \rVert = \sup_n \lVert \mu_n \rVert < \infty$ for all $f \in C(K)$. In this regard I assume that this should also hold for non-compact $E$.
2. For simplicity, I defined above $M$ to be the space of signed Borel measures (the dual of $C_c$ when $C_c$ is equipped with the sup-norm), but I'm more interested in the larger dual of $C_c$ when equipped with the locally convex inductive limit topology, so that $C_c$ is barrelled and one can possibly apply the Banach-Steinhaus theorem - but I don't see how.

Comment: I guess $|\mu_n|\,\mid_K=|\mu_n\mid_K |$  Then the conclusions are true. Just take $K={\rm supp}\, f.$

Comment: Indeed, this helps and the conclusion follows immediately. Thank you. When considering $\mu \in C_c'$ with $C_c = \bigcup_{K \subseteq E \textrm{ compact}} C(E; K)$ (where $C(E; K)$ is the space of continuous functions defined on $E$ with support in $K$ ... $C(E; K)$ is then a Banach space with the sup-norm and the UBP is valid) then define $\mu|_K := \mu|_{C(E;K)}$. If $C_c$ carries the l.c. ind. limit topology then $\mu|_K \in C(E; K)'$.